# speed up drop rows base on pandas column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, numba

I have a very large pandas data frame, which looks something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Station": [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6],
                   "Day": [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
                   "Temp": [-7.0, 2.7, -1.3, -1.9, 0.2, 0.5, 1.3, 6.4]})
```

and I would like to as efficiently (quickly) as possible filter out all rows, which do not have exactly n rows with a certain 'Station' value.

```
stations =  pd.unique(df['Station'])
n = 3

def complete(temp):
    for k in range(len(stations)):
        if len(temp[temp['Station']== stations[k]].Temp) != n:
            temp.drop(temp.index[temp['Station'] == stations[k]], inplace=True)
```

I've been looking into using @jit(nopython=True) or Cython along the lines of this [enhance pandas tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html), but in the examples that I have found the columns are treated separately to each other. I'm wondering, is the fastest way to somehow use @jit to create a new list of `v = df['Station']` only containing the rows that I want and then to use `df = df[df.Station.isin(v)]` to filter out the rows of the entire data frame or is there a better way?

Comment: `df.groupby('Station').filter(lambda x: len(x)==n)`  Wouldn't something like this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `value_counts`:

```
out = df[df['Station'].isin(df['Station'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x==n].index)]
print(out)

# Output
   Station  Day  Temp
0        2    1  -7.0
1        2    2   2.7
2        2    3  -1.3
3        5    1  -1.9
4        5    2   0.2
5        5    3   0.5
```

Result of `value_counts`:

```
>>> df['Station'].value_counts()
2    3
5    3
6    2
Name: Station, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest method with a runtime of 562 µs ± 884 ns per loop. The groupby method is also nice (and maybe also slightly more readable in my opinion), but has a slightly slower runtime of 601 µs ± 12.5 µs per loop. Thank you all for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` "Station" and transform `count` method and compare the counts with `n` to create a boolean Series. Then use this mask to filter the relevant rows:

```
n=3
msk = df.groupby('Station')['Temp'].transform('count').eq(n)
df = df[msk]
```

Output:

```
   Station  Day  Temp
0        2    1  -7.0
1        2    2   2.7
2        2    3  -1.3
3        5    1  -1.9
4        5    2   0.2
5        5    3   0.5
```